# Binomial coefficient and time congestion Propabillity Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, binomial-coefficients

```
def binomialco(p,k):
  Sum = 1
  Pro = 1
  for i in range(0,k):
    Sum = Sum*(p-i)
  for i in range(1,k+1):
    Pro = Pro*i
  return float(Sum/Pro)

def P0(s,n,v,h):
  athroisma = 0
  for i in range(0,s+1):
    dent= binomialco(n-1,i)*(v*h)**i
    athroisma+=dent
  return athroisma

s=input()
n=input()
v=input()
h=input()

print P0(s,n,v,h)
```

Problem is when I give as input the following : `s=2`, `n=4`, `v=float(1/30)` and `h=3` I am supposed to get `1.33`. All i get is `0.0`. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Which version of Python?

Comment: The first step in figuring something like this out is to run `binomialco` separately and see if it's working for you.  People on SO will do this for you, but it would be better for you to do it yourself, because you'd: 1) learn this basic process of programming, and, 2) ask better questions on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing from what you are getting, you must be using py2. Here you will have to coerce to `float` that is you have to `return float(Sum)/float(Pro)`.

This is a small test to make you understand why

```
>>> 1/30
0
>>> float(1/30)
0.0
>>> float(1)/float(30)
0.03333333333333333
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will be better prepared for my question next time.